# Dynamic creation radio view coundn't display

Tags: android, android-layout

In my class I want to set radio group button at start position but is not placing properly. This is my class view:

[image]

**layout.xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
        android:text="more question" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTimeCount"
        style="@style/normalText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="00:00" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity Code:**

```
public class Rate_me_up extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnCheckedChangeListener {
RelativeLayout layout;
int id = 1;
private TextView textViewShowTime;
private long totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 60 * 1 / 4 * 1000;

private long timeBlinkInMilliseconds = 30 * 1000 * 1 / 4;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private boolean blink;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rate_me_up);
    textViewShowTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimeCount);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

    Button btnp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonp);
    btnp.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(Rate_me_up.this);
    radioGroup.setOrientation(0);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.addView(radioGroup, p);
    RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(Rate_me_up.this);
    radioButtonView.setText("radio1");
    radioButtonView.setId(id++);
    radioButtonView.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.e404);
    radioButtonView.setChecked(false);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);

    RadioButton radioButtonView2 = new RadioButton(Rate_me_up.this);
    radioButtonView2.setText("radio2");
    radioButtonView2.setId(id++);
    radioButtonView2.setChecked(false);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView2, p);
    RadioButton radioButtonView3 = new RadioButton(Rate_me_up.this);
    radioButtonView3.setText("radio3");
    radioButtonView3.setId(id++);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView3, p);
    radioButtonView3.setChecked(false);
    TextView txt = new TextView(Rate_me_up.this);

    txt.setText("FOOD QUALITY!");
//  layout.addView(txt, p);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}
```

Comment: You're wondering why `radioGroup.setOrientation(0);` didn't do it I guess, but it's because the radioGroup is inside the RelativeLayout, so it's at position 0 of the RelativeLayout, which you need to change the parameters for - as DejanRistic answered below

Comment: how to do that....plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have your RelativeLayout Params defined, you can simply add a rule to them to align your RadioGroup to the top.

```
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
```

Do this before:

```
layout.addView(radioGroup, p);
```

**EDIT:**

You also need to change the height in your RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to WRAP_CONTENT.

**EDIT 2:**

If you want to dynamically add radio groups below one another, you can do it this way:

First add two instance variables

```
private RadioGroup mLastRadioGroup;
private int mRadioGroupId = 1111; //just a default start id.
```

Then add this line right after assigning your LayoutParams. (Ditch the rule mentioned above if you want dynamic adding)

```
if (mLastRadioGroup != null)
   p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mLastRadioGroup.getId());
```

Then right before you add your radioGroup to your layout, set its id. And assign the mLastRadioGroup to your radio group.

```
radioGroup.setId(mRadioGroupId++);
mLastRadioGroup = radioGroup;
layout.addView(radioGroup, p); // I moved this to the bottom
```

This way we know the last groups id, and we can keep adding a new one below it.

Comment: Is it the same result as in your picture still?

Comment: I don't think you need to pass p to every RadioButton, try using just addView(radioButton). Since your orientation is already set they should line up fine. Just need it for the group. That may not fix it though, Ill try to reproduce your code and see what it is.

Comment: See my edit, changing the height to wrap_content instead of match_parent should fix it

Comment: Oh so every time you press the button, you want another radio group to be created? Below the previous one?

Comment: See Edit 2 for dynamic adding :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's because the height of your second `RelativeLayout` in your xml file, `android:layout_height="150dp"`, needs to be set to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`